# How can I insert a Variable from PHP into a Java Script Variable with a direct variable?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I put a variable value from PHP $name, into a Java script variable, so I can insert it into this offline openDatabase for testing.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=app', 'user' , 'password');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into registered(msg) values (?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $msg);
$msg= $_POST["msg1"];
?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
     var msg = $name; //how can I make this a $name php variable?

     db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, "msg")');//put $name into here from php
        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you try `var msg=<?php echo $msg; ?>;`?

Comment: `<?php echo $name; ?>;`

Comment: Or another way is to use AJAX. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: It was so simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple! Just do this way:

```
<script>
    var x = <?php echo $msg; ?>;
</script>
```